# django external script ImportError: No module named Utils

Tags: django

I search google and this forum and i found this solution

```
sth=os.path.abspath('/home/artur/Desktop')
sys.path.append(sth)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
```

Every think seems to be ok even my editor provide support for import statement. And when i try to import my models i get thiss

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app_name.models import *
  File "app's models models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import DateField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django import forms
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/forms/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from widgets import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/forms/widgets.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils.html import escape, conditional_escape
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/utils/html.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import urlquote
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/utils/http.py", line 4, in <module>
    from email.Utils import formatdate
ImportError: No module named Utils
```

I try to google around this but can't find nothing to help solve this(found some similar way to add django settings file but all failed with the same error).My OS is Debian testing and python 2.6.6.  Thanks for any help or sugestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`email.Utils` is a python standard library module. Do you have a module called `email` that's conflicting with it?

Go into a shell and type in

```
import email
print email.__file__ # where is this "email" module? 
# make sure it's not one of yours...
```

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.6/email/__init__.pyc
No i don't add any modules or have my own which are calld email.

Comment: No file named email in `/home/artur/Desktop`?

Comment: Oh wait, appending to sys.path shouldn't cause that.

Comment: I should consider killing myself:/ I have in my project email.py file which I renamed and problem disappear.Thanks Yuji for your tips they are really helpful;)

Comment: Ahh, wait don't do that! Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: This is perfect! I'm building a django application and had created an app called `email` that was overriding the standard library's module. Thanks for pointing out the gotcha!